# Magento 2 UI Form without collection

Tags: magento2.2, uicomponent, adminform

can i build a Magento 2 Ui Form without use Collection at DataProvider Class?
If i don't use a valid collection not seems to work...

I just want to use the form to post data to external source. I don't know if this is the most appropriate way or i have to use a phtml form.

```
 protected $name;
protected $primaryFieldName;
protected $requestFieldName;
protected $meta;
protected $data;
protected $collection;

public function __construct(
    $name,
    $primaryFieldName,
    $requestFieldName,
    //CollectionFactory $myCollectionFactory,
    array $meta = [],
    array $data = []
)
{
    parent::__construct($name, $primaryFieldName, $requestFieldName, $meta, $data);
    //$this->collection = $myCollectionFactory->create();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, You can create Ui component form without a database.

If  you want to use phtml then also you can use that

Using ui component You need  to add following into your code

For this, Your Data Provider should be like

```
<dataSource name="coupon_email_data_source">
        <argument name="dataProvider" xsi:type="configurableObject">
            <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">Namespace\ModuleName\Model\DataProvider</argument>
            <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">coupon_email_data_source</argument>
            <argument name="primaryFieldName" xsi:type="string">id</argument>
            <argument name="requestFieldName" xsi:type="string">id</argument>
        </argument>
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/provider</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
</dataSource>
```

> Namespace\ModuleName\Model\DataProvider

And create Your DataProvider.php In Model Directory like Model/DataProvider.php

```
namespace Namespace\ModuleName\Model;


class DataProvider extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\DataProvider
{
    /**
     * Get data
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getData()
    {
        return [];
    }

}
```

You will see the form then.